# PHP/MySQL : UPDATE multiples values with multiples WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The problem I'm having is with a strategy browser game which has 7 types of values. The problems are as follows:

1. I got 7 different values in `$_POST`, from index unit_1 to index unit_7 included. These 7 values are INTEGERS between 0 and 20 and aren't static. They can at each call of the page. They represent the number of units sent.
2. I got 7 lines in a table that does not follow the same schema : `"nameUnit" = "Soldier"` && `nbUnit = "0"`, `"nameUnit" = "Mage"` && `nbUnit = "5"`, etc..
3. I need to do an update on the number of units in 1 request, but I don't know how to do this.

Example of what I want to do :

```
UPDATE x SET nbUnit = $_POST['u1'] WHERE nameUnit = "Soldier", nbUnit = $_POST['u2'] WHERE nameUnit = "Mage" [...]
```

Is it possible to do this that way and can it be done in a single query?

Comment: If the values updated (`SET` clause) are the same, you can use the clause `OR`. If the values are different, you have the create one update for each statement.

Comment: Check MySQL CASE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: Worked with CASE. Thanx you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN PL SQL you can do the following :

```
UPDATE x SET nbUnit = case when nameUnit = "Soldier" then $_POST['u1'] 
when nameUnit = "Mage" then $_POST['u2'] else nbUnit end;
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work perfectly. Is this possible to do "THEN nbUnit + $_POST['u1']" to increment ?

Comment: after then expression comes which can represent a value as mentioned in Oracle : In a simple CASE expression, Oracle Database searches for the first WHEN ... THEN pair for which expr is equal to comparison_expr and returns return_expr. If none of the WHEN ... THEN pairs meet this condition, and an ELSE clause exists, then Oracle returns else_expr. Otherwise, Oracle returns null. You cannot specify the literal NULL for every return_expr and the else_expr.

Comment: I understand. I got this working perfectly using CASE. For information, I used to do UPDATE x SET y = CASE [...] ELSE y END WHERE z = xxxx, and it seems to work. It must be way better than using AND on a WHEN clause. Thanx for everything !

Answer (score 1):

this work in ur case

```
UPDATE x 
SET nbUnit = $_POST['u1'] 
WHERE (nameUnit = "Soldier" AND nbUnit = $_POST['u2']) OR 
(nameUnit = "Mage" AND nbUnit= $_POST['u5'])
```